# How to zip multiple files or folders with WinSCP and automatically keep the file name part?

Tags: winscp

I am using WinSCP and it has the option to use custom commands remotely.

I want to zip some files and folders. WinSCP has a command that can zip a file or folder but I have to enter the name for the zip to be called.

```
zip -r "!?&Enter an Archive Name:?archive.zip!" !&
```

I would like a command that will take the name of the file and use that for the zip.

I.e. `thisnewvideo.mp4` to become `thisnewvideo.zip`.

I have a lot of files so typing each title will take a long time.

If it is possible I would like to be able to do multiple files at once and create a separate zip file for each file or folder keeping to original file or folder title.

It needs to be a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP does not have a pattern or any other mechanism to extract filename without extension (or substitute the extension).

Anyway, you can use any function that the server provides to achieve the same. For example you can replace the extension using the `sed` command:

```
echo thisnewvideo.mp4 | sed 's/\..*$/.zip/'
```

This will output:

```
 thisnewvideo.zip
```

You can merge this into the WinSCP custom command using backtick operator like:

```
zip -r `echo ! | sed 's/\..*$/.zip/'` !
```

Note that the command is using the [`!` pattern](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_command). When you execute it for a set of selected files, it gets executed once for every file, producing one `.zip` file for every source file.

For alternatives see: [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/850848).

Note that I would consider better (and easier) to implement it to just append the `.zip` extension (i.e. `thisnewvideo.mp4.zip`) to the end of the file name, rather than substituting the extension. You would avoid name clashes, if you have two files with the same base name, just a different extension. But I do not know your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
zip -r `echo ! | sed 's/\..*$/.zip/'` !
```

It's ok if you want multiple zip

And monster like that

```
ls -q !& > list_1239.txt; zip -9 "!?&FileName:?archive.zip!" $(cat list_1239.txt); rm list_1239.txt
```

if you want one big zip-file with custom name